# error C2504: 'ios' : base class undefined

Tags: c++

I am trying my hands on sample codes from a book, and so I am not entirely sure what I may have wrong in the header file I have so far.

I keep getting the following error messages.

**Error 2   error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'streambuf'

Error   1   error C2504: 'ios' : base class undefined

Error   5   IntelliSense: identifier "streambuf" is undefined**

```
// StdAfx.h HEADER FILE 
**************************
// stdafx.h : include file for standard system include files,
// or project specific include files that are used frequently, but
// are changed infrequently
//

#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <strstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <ios>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include "targetver.h"


// Conios HEADER FILE 
**************************

#include "Stdafx.h"



class Conios :virtual public ios{
protected:
public:

    Conios(void);
    ~Conios(void);
     Conios(streambuf* Buffer);
};
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ios` is in the `std`-namespace. So either use `use namespace std;` or extend from `std::ios` instead of just `ios`.

If you are using `use namespace` use it only in your implementation-files like `*.cpp` or `*.cxx`, do **not** write `use namespace ...` your header files - ever!.

And the same goes for `streambuf`.

Comment: Advising him to use `use namespace std;` is really bad bad advice. A better advice would be telling him to **not** use it ever.

Comment: @Nawaz: You are right, I have added that in my answer (but using `use namespace` in implementation files is accepted, isn't it?).